# Configure Redisson client to simulataneously use two codecs

Tags: json, replication, codec, snappy, redisson

We use Redisson & are experimenting with **Snappy compression codec** to reduce Redis storage. We currently use **JSON code**c for custom data serialization.
For the purpose of rollbacks on production, **I'm exploring if it is possible to run the Redisson client to simultaneously write to 2 Redis servers**: one with Snappy codec & the other with JSON codec. **Any suggestions are highly appreciated**

Answer (score 1):

Redisson client writes only to a single Redis setup (cluster, sentinel, replicated or single). You can implement RedissonClient interface with wrapper of two Redisson instances. This wrapper should execute operations in parallel through Async-interface.

Answer (score 0):

We use database and NameMapper for this functionality.
The new version of your app with use updated DB and Updated Values using a different NameMapper.